# Certificate Pinning for android using OKHTTP

Tags: android, okhttp

I need to do certificate pinning using certificate but I do not know where to start request and handle response... can anyone suggest step by step tutorial for this?

Comment: Have you seen this https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html ? Question looks like very broad

Comment: yes, but how to I add my certificate...Thanks

Comment: "Follow up by pasting the public key hashes from the exception into the certificate pinner's configuration:"
   

    CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
           .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=")
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=")
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/grX4Ta9HpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=")
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=")
       .build();

Comment: By specifying a hostname and the corresponding public key hash. Does it answer the question?

Comment: I have server intermediate certificate i have to do pinning by using that....Thank you

Answer (score 0):

we can set certificate pinning by value.,..

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(65, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Call methods for certificate pinning

```
    public static void addCertificatePinner(OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder) {
        CertificatePinner.Builder certificatePinnerBuilder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();
        certificatePinnerBuilder.add("url", certificatePublicKey);// certificatePublicKey as String key
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = certificatePinnerBuilder.build();
        httpBuilder.certificatePinner(certificatePinner);
    }
```